# Node JS Microservice with Moleculer

Tags: javascript, node.js, moleculer

I am using Node JS and trying to understand the Microservice structure.

As a result of my research, I found a framework named "Moleculer". I started using this and it works fine on my computer.

I want to create a new project in my project, run brokers in new projects and load those projects into docker.

-First of all, can I take each Broker into a separate project and keep these projects in Docker?

-If I cannot make partitioning like this, then my project will still be Monolithic, how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create two separate moleculer project and then since they have a connection to the same external transporter let's say NATS then they can exchange events between them.

For more information check this article:

https://dankuida.com/moleculer-deployment-thoughts-8e0fc8c0fb07